# How to know when to treat a problem as a classification task or a regression task?

Tags: classification, regression

Facing this dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine+quality I treated it both as a classification task and as a regression task.

Due to the fact that classifying the quality of a wine as 8 while it is a 3 is a huge difference while classifying a 5 as 6 is not that bad

This has two subquestions:

1. Is there an easy way to change the weight of the classification in a (scikit-learn) classifier?
2. Following the regression approach and having the output being rounded to the nearest valid wine quality value (converting the outputs to a classifier-like outputs) hides any pitfalls?

Many thanks

Comment: The funny thing is that your problem really calls for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression

Comment: Yeah I think you are correct. I am now reading the "a simple approach to ordinal classification". It feels better to treat it as an ordinal classification than any kind of regression. Would you agree? Reference: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/df47/a60a50f4ddde9a4fe3b560091ba925cfd495.pdf

Comment: For this particular problem I would first try ordinal regression, then regular regression.

Comment: You can find the answer here:-
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/69524/81999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ordinal classification. A quick approach to handle this with any classifier that outputs probabilities is explained thoroughly [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/df47/a60a50f4ddde9a4fe3b560091ba925cfd495.pdf).

In a few words: if you have, for example, three ordinal classes $Cool < Mild < Hot$, then you create binary classifiers.

For the first and last class you calculate the probabilities immediately like so:

#### Is temperature larger than $cool$?

This is given by $P(temp > cool)$, where, $P(temp = cool) = 1 - P(temp > cool)$

#### Is temperature larger than $mild$?

You calculate (neither mild or cool) as: $P(temp > mild)$, therefore $P(temp = hot) = P(temp > mild)$

#### Is the temperature $mild$?

All the intermediate classifications (here we have only one) result from subtractions. We have all the cases larger than $cool$ (here $mild$ and $hot$)
but we also remove the probability of being larger than $mild$.

This leaves us with the probability of being just $mild$:
$$P(temp = mild) = P(temp > cool) - P(temp > mild)$$

Answer (score 3):

In effect it is ordinal regression/classification. I suggest you to go for Mean Absolute Error to take into account the missclassification that play a bigger role when far from the ground truth :

$MAE = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n|h(x_i) - y_i|}{n}$, creating your own scoring function in python.

Given the number of different outputs you have, I recommend you to go for regression. Anyway, rounding any hypothesis output would only play on the score, it's up to you to decide if it makes more sense to see wine quality scores as classes or not.